# PerfectNumber messes with my iterator

Tags: bugs, warning-messages, iterators

*I am using Mathematica 10.4 (sorry bbgodfrey) (temporary message)*

Let

```
mmVerbose = 10^2000 + 123123798797192983712873198273122323;
kkVerbose = 10^7;
```

The following gives an error.

```
Do[PerfectNumber[iterator],
 {iterator, mmVerbose, mmVerbose + kkVerbose}]
```

But the following doesn't.

```
Do[1, {iterator, mmVerbose, mmVerbose + kkVerbose}]
```

Also a loop with a time consuming argument does not give an error.

```
Do[Pause[3]; 
 Print@iterator, {iterator, mmVerbose, mmVerbose + kkVerbose}]
```

I can accept that `Do` guards against ranges that are too big, like in the following code.

```
Do[1, {iterator, 1, mmVerbose + kkVerbose}]
```

I am wondering what makes `PerfectNumber` so special and why the `Message` is displayed. Note that you can use `PrintDefinitions` on `PerfectNumber` and get a lot of information.

Comment: PerfectNumber is not recognized in 10.3.1.  What version are you using?

Comment: @bbgodfrey `PerfectNumber` is a new function in Mathematica 10.4.0

Comment: ...but what *is* the message that you get?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The error message does not come from your own `Do` loop, but from a `Do` loop inside the `PerfectNumber` code somewhere:

```
In[9]:= PerfectNumber[mmVerbose]

During evaluation of In[9]:= Do::iterb: Iterator {100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000123123798797192983712873198273122323-SymbolicTensors`UtilitiesDump`temp$maxRankedN$328507} does not have appropriate bounds. >>

[...]

Out[9]= SymbolicTensors`UtilitiesDump`RankedPerfectNumber[18]
```

I think this can be tagged as a bug in `PerfectNumber` not handling large arguments perfectly. I reported it to the developer.

Comment: Ah yes I came to this conclusion also. I have a bad internet connection at the moment, so I didn't catch yours. I think it is kind of reasonable that `PerfectNumber` does not handle the large input, I think it probably the number `PerfectNumber[2^63 + 1000]` would not fit in the universe. I guess a nicer error message could have helped, but I don't want to be too harsh on symbols with attribute `ReadProtected` (and visible definitions).

Comment: I got confused because the error for `Do` with a large range is the same as the message generated `PerfectNumberQ` for a large number.